# Weights in RollingWLS

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels, weighted

I have a RollingWLS model with one dependent variable and 10 independent variables. I am calculating a RollingWLS multivariate regression over 60 windows.

```
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingWLS

endog = df1
exog = df2
cov_type = 'HC0'

wls_model = RollingWLS(endog, exog, window=60)
wls = wls_model.fit(cov_type=cov_type)
```

The data exhibits heteroscedasticity, which I would like to correct for using the `Weights` parameter in RollingWLS.

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingWLS.html

> A 1d array of weights. If you supply 1/W then the variables are pre- multiplied by 1/sqrt(W). If no weights are supplied the default value is 1 and WLS results are the same as OLS.

How should I calculate Rolling Weights for the RollingWLS `Weights` function? I.e.:

```
wls_model = RollingWLS(endog, exog, **ROLLING_WEIGHTS_HERE**, window=60)
wls = wls_model.fit(cov_type=cov_type)
```

Thanks